# Empty data insert on every page reload

Tags: php

I have a problem about posting data to DB.When i reload the page,or go to the website,it sends null data to DB.Its because i haven't functioned the button(well,i mean an onclick event) for this.Directly wrote a php code under the form and it works if you fill the spaces such as text and textarea and click the button.Though,Im new to PHP,So what I exactly need is,learning how to function a button to insert data to database using PHP to prevent inserting data on every load of form.

Here is the code

```
<?php
        $host="localhost";
        $user="root";
        $password="";
        $db="mkappform";

        $con=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$password","$db");
        if (! $con) die ("Unable to connect to database");

        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $nick=$_POST["nick"];
        $pvnick=$_POST["pvnick"];
        $age=$_POST["age"];
        $country=$_POST["country"];
        $timezone=$_POST["timezone"];
        $servers=$_POST["servers"];
        $checkban=$_POST["checkban"];
        $contact=$_POST["contact"];
        $history=$_POST["history"];
        $reasons=$_POST["reasons"];
        $whypastclans=$_POST["whypastclans"];
        $anyotherinfo=$_POST["anyotherinfo"];




        $query=mysqli_query($con,
        "INSERT INTO mkappform(name,nick,pvnick,age,country,timezone,servers,checkban,contact,history,reasons,whypastclans,anyotherinfo) 
        values('$name','$nick','$pvnick','$age','$country','$timezone','$servers','$checkban','$contact','$history','$reasons','$whypastclans','$anyotherinfo')");
        if($query == true)
        echo "Application was sent successfully!!"
        ?>
```

Comment: Koray i gave suggestions and answer too, please check all answers and mark and up-vote one which one works for you and will be descriptive as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use action attribute of your form. For example action="index.php?action=form"
Because `isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)` is most of time not enough if you are dealing with bigger webapp.

```
    if(isset($_GET["action"]
    {
       //Open database
       switch($_GET["action"])
    {
      case "form":
        //callYourForm
         form();
       break;

      case "anotherThing":
         anotherThing();
       break;
//can do more things if needed..
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use [PDO statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) instead of **mysqli** it is better and simple.

2) Using `'$name'` will be equal to `'$name'` because using **single quote** take the string as it is, instead use **double quote** like this `"$name"`.

3) Here an example that uses the previous **notes** :

```
<?php
        $host="localhost";
        $user="root";
        $password="";
        $db="mkappform";

        try {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db","$user","$password");

                $name=$_POST["name"];
                $nick=$_POST["nick"];
                $pvnick=$_POST["pvnick"];
                $age=$_POST["age"];
                $country=$_POST["country"];
                $timezone=$_POST["timezone"];
                $servers=$_POST["servers"];
                $checkban=$_POST["checkban"];
                $contact=$_POST["contact"];
                $history=$_POST["history"];
                $reasons=$_POST["reasons"];
                $whypastclans=$_POST["whypastclans"];
                $anyotherinfo=$_POST["anyotherinfo"];

               $insert_status = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO mkappform(name,nick,pvnick,age,country,timezone,servers,checkban,contact,history,reasons,whypastclans,anyotherinfo)
                values('$name','$nick','$pvnick','$age','$country','$timezone','$servers','$checkban','$contact','$history','$reasons','$whypastclans','$anyotherinfo')");
                if($insert_status){
                        echo "Application was sent successfully!!"                        
                }else{
                        echo "an error occured when inserting data";
                }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage(); 
                die("Unable to connect to database");
        }

        ?>
```

**In reality we use parameter binding when inserting into databases to avoid SQL Injections**

Comment: Can you give me a reason @Anant why #1  is not valid ?

Comment: because both are equally good and have there own ability. And before asking me, let me know why you write first line. You need to gave some example

Comment: you are right  @Anant i should write an example but using PDO makes your life easier as it is simple and **Object oriented** and pleasing to look at.